# Bar Graph in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

```
Can any one provide good library of Bar chart to display win loss for 50 objects.
I have search for bar graphs libraries but maximum are Shift language I need graph in Objective-c.
I have done single bar chart but I want double bar charts.
```

> For single Bar graph I am used E-CHART Library from Git hub

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdyPi.png
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this library, it has worked for me as it gives you more options. 
:-https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: can you Please explain how to drag the file and convert in to the shift to objective-c

Comment: download the demo project from the given link :- https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Objective-C